# How to convert String to int and compare it by using Comparator

Tags: java, android, arrays, spring, arraylist

This is how i am comparing 2 Strings value, the values are in number, It works perfectly fine until it receive a value equal or greater than 10.

So i need to convert these values to integer.

`TXCartData` class has `String rowID`

This is what i was doing.

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<TXCartData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
        return lhs.rowId.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.rowId);
    }
});
```

I have tried to change `rowID` to integer, but its giving me an error message, as its expecting 0 or 1 in output, and `1==1` returns `true` of `false`.

This is what i tried.

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<TXCartData>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
        return Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId)== Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId);
    }
});
```

The data list is very large, I sort it three times by using `Comparator`and get accurate result, The first 2 are strings and it sorted them accurately, but on the last one it fails.

Comment: Is your String purely contains integer number only ?

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal , Yes the `rowID` will always contain `int`, but i cannot change it on class  level, i need to convert it to `int`

Comment: you want to sort arraylist ?

Comment: `var rowIdInt = Integer.parseInt(rowID);` try it

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Yes that's an arrayList,but contains different type of data, I first need to sort it section wise, that are string, then row wise, and seat wise. The first 2 are working fine.

Comment: you can filter arraylist only bases on single parameter at one time

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Yes i do the same, 1 first sort it section wise, then row wise and then seat wise

Comment: arraylist contains model class ?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Yes Its a simple pojo class

Comment: What is generic type of data ? @Kirmani88

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pls try this

```
 Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<TXCartData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
            int n1=Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId);
            int n2=Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId);
            if (n1>=n2){
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Classes that has a natural sort order (a class Number, as an example) should implement the Comparable interface, whilst classes that has no natural sort order (a class Chair, as an example) should be provided with a Comparator (or an anonymous Comparator class).

```
public class Number implements Comparable<Number> {
    private int value;

    public Number(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public int compareTo(Number anotherInstance) {
        return this.value - anotherInstance.value;
    }
}

public class Chair {
    private int weight;
    private int height;

    public Chair(int weight, int height) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }
    /* Omitting getters and setters */
}
class ChairWeightComparator implements Comparator<Chair> {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        return chair1.getWeight() - chair2.getWeight();
    }
}
class ChairHeightComparator implements Comparator<Chair> {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        return chair1.getHeight() - chair2.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
...
Collections.sort(numbers);

List<Chair> chairs = new ArrayList<Chair>();
// Sort by weight:
Collections.sort(chairs, new ChairWeightComparator());
// Sort by height:
Collections.sort(chairs, new ChairHeightComparator());

// You can also create anonymous comparators;
// Sort by color:
Collections.sort(chairs, new Comparator<Chair>() {
    public int compare(Chair chair1, Chair chair2) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `return` type of your compare function

```
public boolean compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
        return Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId)== Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId);
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me error message, and forcing to convert `boolean` into `int`

Comment: is this a default function or your function ? if its your's then change it in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing fine just change '==' to '-' in your code. This will work ...

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<TXCartData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
        return Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId)- Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Integer.compare(int,int) and Integer.lowestOneBit(int)

int result = Integer.lowestOneBit(Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(number1), Integer.parseInt(number2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort in **descending** order of lhs.rowId , below code for it

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<TXCartData>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(TXCartData lhs, TXCartData rhs) {
        return Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId) - Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId);
    }
});
```

For **ascending** order return statement can be changed to below,

```
return Integer.parseInt(rhs.rowId) - Integer.parseInt(lhs.rowId);
```